# pull all database values in dropdown

Tags: jsp, jdbc

i have a jsp that gets a dropdown values from a database. here what i want is to get data of all the users. the query i have is as below

```
SELECT type, SUM(Update_Count) FROM Scope1 where type in ('Updates','Multibases','DAIS','Acds','Legis','LegAll') and Specialist in ('Rakesh') and (RECVD_DATE >='04/01/2012' and RECVD_DATE <='04/30/2012') group by type
```

here i have 2 users as hari and rakesh. i want my jsp to give the below query when i select All in dropdown.

```
 SELECT type, SUM(Update_Count) FROM Scope1 where type in ('Updates','Multibases','DAIS','Acds','Legis','LegAll') and Specialist in ('Rakesh','Hari') and (RECVD_DATE >='04/01/2012' and RECVD_DATE <='04/30/2012') group by type
```

the jsp i use is as below.

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@include file="DBCon.jsp" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
            }
        });
        $( "#to" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

    </head> 
    <body><form name="Reports" method="post" action="DropDown.jsp"><table><tr>

                     <td>From</td><td><input type="text" id="from" name="from"></td></tr>

                     <tr><td>To</td><td><input type="text" id="to" name="to"></td></tr>
                     <tr><td>Select user:</td><td><select name="user" id="user">


            <option value="">Select User</option>
            <%
            try{
                ps=con.prepareStatement("Select Distinct Specialist from Scope1");
                rs=ps.executeQuery();
                while(rs.next()){
              %>
                <option value="<%String user1=rs.getString(1);out.println(user1);%>"><%out.println(user1);%></option>
                <%
            }
            out.println("<select>");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
                                       {
                out.println(e);
            }
            %>

                             </select></td></tr>
                     <tr><td>
        Select Type:</td><td><select name="type" id="type">
            <option value="">Select Type</option>
            <option value="'Updates','Multibases','DAIS','Acds','Legis','LegAll'">All</option>
            <%
            try{
                ps=con.prepareStatement("Select Distinct type from Scope1");
                rs=ps.executeQuery();
                while(rs.next()){
        %>
                <option value="'<%String type1=rs.getString(1).trim();out.print(type1);%>'"><%out.println(type1.trim());%></option>
                <%
            }
            out.println("<Select>");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
                                       {
                out.println(e);
            }
            %>
                            </select></td></tr>
                     <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Generate" id="sub1" name="sub1"></td></tr>
        </table> </form>   </body>
</html>
```

and for retrieving i use the below code

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@include file="DBCon.jsp" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body><table>
        <%
        String a=request.getParameter("type").trim();
        String b=request.getParameter("user").trim();
        String c=request.getParameter("from").trim();
        String d=request.getParameter("to").trim();
        try{
            String sql=("SELECT type, SUM(Update_Count) FROM Scope1 where type in ("+a+") and Specialist='"+b+"' and (RECVD_DATE >='"+c+"' and RECVD_DATE <='"+d+"') group by type");
            out.print(sql);
            //ps1=con.prepareStatement("SELECT type, SUM(Update_Count) FROM Scope1 where type in ("+a+") and Specialist='"+b+"' and (RECVD_DATE >='"+c+"' and RECVD_DATE <='"+d+"') group by type");
            //rs1=ps1.executeQuery();
            while(rs1.next())
            {
            %>
            <tr><td><%=rs1.getString(1)%></td><td><%=rs1.getString(2)%></td></tr>
            <%
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            out.println(e);
    }
%>
   </table> </body>
</html>
```

also i want the below line also dynamic i.e. not having option value, it should be taken from database.

```
<option value="'Updates','Multibases','DAIS','Acds','Legis','LegAll'">All</option>
```

please help me .

Thanks

Comment: SO.... what is your question?

Comment: @rakesh Which query do you are using to populate your option values?

Comment: i'm using ps=con.prepareStatement("Select Distinct Specialist from Scope1");
                rs=ps.executeQuery();
                while(rs.next()){
              %>
                <option value="<%String user1=rs.getString(1);out.println(user1);%>"><%out.println(user1);%></option>
                <%
            } but this will only pull one user i.e. 1 in each dropdown, i want it to pull all the users in All

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in a class that executes the select query and retrieves the data. Save those data in an ArrayList.

In your jsp call that method and with a combination of html and java (scriplet) populate the drop down box

JSP:

```
<%
ArrayList list = yourClass.getData();
int size = list.size();
%>
<select name="someName">
<%
for (int i=0;i<size;i++) 
{  
String s = (String)list.get(i);
%>

<option value="<%=s%>" ><%=s%></option>

<%}%>

    </select>
```

If the above code is confusing or doesn't make sense then you should do more studying about JSPs and html

Also you should already know how to run queries or use java core methods before going to JSP.
For your method that runs the query, better create a class that has a combination of 2 attributes (value, text). The ArrayList should have elements not Strings but of the class you created. When you run the query you would need a value to display and a value to use :

JSP:

```
<%

ArrayList list = yourClass.getData();
int size = list.size();

%>

<select name="someName">

<%for (int i=0;i<size;i++) 
{  

YourClass obj = (YourClass)list.get(i);

%>

<option value="<%=obj.getValue()%>" ><%=obj.getText()%></option>

<%}%>

</select>
```